# In English grammar, is a mathematical expression considered a clause or a noun phrase?

Tags: article-writing

In English grammar, is a mathematical expression considered a clause or a noun phrase?

When I read the mathematical proof, I find that it is not uniform for authors to treat the mathematical expression.

e.g., (1) That "$x>2$" implies that "$y>2$".

(2) "$x>2$" implies "$y>2$".

In (1), the mathematical expression is considered a clause, while in (2), the mathematical expression is considered a noun.
Which one is right?

Comment: There is no right or wrong here : It is a **"Stylistic Choice"** : Check out **"Mathematical Writing"** by Donald E. Knuth, Tracy Larrabee, and Paul M. Roberts.

Comment: I would argue the only nouns are variables and constants above, whereas the premise and antecedents are clauses with a connective in between.

Comment: The version (1) is just acceptable, but I find (2) better. Taking the bad priniple that math notation just abbreviates english language to the worst extreme leads to "sentences" like "How does $A=B?$" which you can find frequently on MSE.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. They are very useful for people who are puzzled about this, like me...